# how to solve "Unresolved reference 'unpack'" in python3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, reference

when I check the code in [kaggle 3hr-tensorrt-nextvit-example](https://www.kaggle.com/code/hengck23/3hr-tensorrt-nextvit-example), I find there is a error that I can not solve. it is called **Unresolved reference** '**unpack**'.what should I do?

```
unc_data = unpack(unpack_fmt, cast(bytes, item.LUTData))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## import the symbol

`unpack` is probably a symbol you need to import in your file.
If you don't import it or define yourself a function named `unpack`, python will tell you with this error. Can you put this on top of your file?

```py
from struct import unpack
```

The way `unpack` is called looks like this function is the one from the built-in library.